# Exclude last row when reading a CSV file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a CSV file, I want to read it and exclude the last raw

Because it's not comma separated

I tried this `data = csvread(file_name, 0, 0, [0, 0, numLines-1, 3])`

where `numLines` is the number of lines and `3` is the number of colums

I'm getting `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

How to fix that

Thank you

Comment: As the column number starts from `0`, you need to use `2` instead of `3` to define the last column. This should avoid the error.try it.

Comment: @Naveen I figured that out, please answer the question and I'll mark it as right